# How to inherit DatabaseContext as a base class across multiple injected services

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, autofac, dbcontext

I have the following setup of a code first database with migrations in .NET Framework, and looking for what feels like there should be a better way of inheriting the `DatabaseContext` for CRUD to the database.

I am using Autofac dependency injection, and intend on having separate classes which inherit some form of `BaseDatabaseContext` class, to save me injecting the `DatabaseContext` class every class I write.

A sample data service class:-

```
public class UserRepo : BaseDatabaseContext, IUserRepo {
    public User WithCredentials(string emailAddress, string password) {
        return _database.Users.Where(x => x.EmailAddress == emailAddress && x.PasswordHash == password).SingleOrDefault();
    }
}
```

The `BaseDatabaseContext` class:

```
public class BaseDatabaseContext {
    public readonly DatabaseContext _database;

    public BaseDatabaseContext() {
        _database = new DatabaseContext();
    }
}
```

The `DatabaseContext` class:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext {
    public DatabaseContext() : base("MainDatabase") {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
       /// stuff here
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    // ... more DbSet's here
}
```

The above works, but I am extremely unkeen, on new-ing up a new DatabaseContext() every time. I feel like I could achieve this through dependency injection but can't figure it.

My overall aim is to have the `BaseDatabaseContext` to basically have a public variable called, for example, `database` that is simple ready to go, and when inherited by the `UserRepo` class, I can call `database.Users.XXX` for example.

Can anyone point out where I am going off track? Or is what I have implemented (which does work), the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am extremely unkeen, on new-ing up a new DatabaseContext() every time. I feel like I could achieve this through dependency injection but can't figure it.

If BaseDatabaseContext has a "dependency" on DatabaseContext, then "inject" it, typically using "construcor injection", but AutoFac also supports [Property Injection](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html):

```
public class BaseDatabaseContext {
    public readonly DatabaseContext _database;

    public BaseDatabaseContext(DatabaseContext db) {
        _database = db;
    }
}
```

A simpler pattern might be to just have your DbContext implement each of the interfaces, perhaps using [Explicit Interface Implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation) to avoid cluttering-up the DatabaseContext API.  eg

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext, IUserRepo {
    public DatabaseContext() : base("MainDatabase") {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
       /// stuff here
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    // ... more DbSet's here

    public User IUserRepo.WithCredentials(string emailAddress, string password) {
        return this.Users.Where(x => x.EmailAddress == emailAddress && x.PasswordHash == password).SingleOrDefault();
    }
}
```